# Proof of 1 = 0, use of ill-formed statements

Tags: logic, fake-proofs, paradoxes

In his book "Analysis 1", Terence Tao writes:

> A logical argument should not contain any ill-formed
>   statements, thus for instance if an argument uses a statement such
>   as x/y = z, it needs to first ensure that y is not equal to zero.
>   Many purported proofs of “0=1” or other false statements rely on
>   overlooking this “statements must be well-formed” criterion.

Can you give an example of such a proof of "0=1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x = y.

Then$ x^2 = xy$

Subtract the same thing from both sides:

$x^2- y^2= xy - y^2$

**Dividing** by (x-y), obtain

x + y = y.

Since x = y, we see that

2 y = y.

Thus 2 = 1, since we started with y nonzero.

Subtracting 1 from both sides,

1 = 0.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the assumption
$$x = 0$$
Divide both sides by $x$ to get
$$x/x=0/x$$
and thus
$$1=0$$

That's the general scheme. Of course it generally gets more obfuscated, for example by starting with the assumption $a+b=c$ and then later dividing both sides with $c-a-b$.